# How to write htaccess wildcard condition

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have this

```
#RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^([^\.]+)\.localhost$ [NC]
#RewriteRule ^$ /s/index.php?s=%1 [L]
```

In this case, whenever i called test.localhost for e.g., it will get content from localhost/s/index.php?s=test

However, when i type www.localhost in the address bar, by right it should not get content from /s/index.php.

How do i write condition in htaccess.

for instance, if is www = do not get content from /s/index.php

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need another `RewriteCond` to exclude `www.`:

```
# Matches all subdomains:
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^([^\.]+)\.localhost$ [NC]
# But then excludes www.
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
RewriteRule ^$ /s/index.php?s=%1 [L]
```

Answer (score 1):

So you want *.localhost to access localhost/s/index.php?s=* for everything *except* www.localhost? The easiest and most specific way is:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^([^\.]+)\.localhost$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !=www.localhost [NC]
RewriteRule ^$ /s/index.php?s=%1 [L]
```

This uses RewriteCond's "lexically equal" check, which should be the most accurate and a tiny bit faster than regexes.